# Did Python pandas to_csv add decimal separator support, like read_csv?

Tags: python, pandas, decimal, export-to-csv, separator

I just noticed (in pandas 0.16.x) there is now a `decimal` parameter in `read_csv()` method. It's really useful and simplifies a lot when reading European CSV files (with comma decimal separator).

I didn't see the same feature in `to_csv()`.

Is there same reason not to have it or just a question of time or release. I would appreciate very much having this feature too.

Comment: Looks like it is there to me.  Not sure when it was added, but I'm using version 0.16.2.

Comment: You're right, it is added since version 0.16.0 (I was using 0.13.2). Thanks a lot, it's wonderful for me and for all the european users.